# Redirecting URL and sub directory to another URL and sub directory via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website which is being hosted using the main URL:
https://www.mainurl.com and I'm using Apache 2.4.

I also have a second URL which is redirected to a sub directory of my main URL:
https://www.secondurl.com --> https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory

This has been achieved using the following in .htacess:

```
### Sub Directory Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.secondurl\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]

### Redirect to WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainurl\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mainurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

### Enforcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, I have also been tasked with redirecting https://www.secondurl.com/manual --> https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory

I'm embarrassed to admit I've been trying to get this to work for the past 3 hours with no success.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get this to work?

Thanks in advance for any help -- super stressed out right now!

Comment: This would seem to already be handled by your first rule? That first rule redirects _everything_ that is targetted at your second domain to `/subdirectory` on your main domain. Unless you literally just want to be redirected to `/subdirectory/` and not `/subdirectory/manual`? What happens exactly when you try this? Also make sure you've cleared your browser cache and better to test with 302s, rather than 301s.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding 302 redirects to test with!

And yes, strangely enough yes, they also wanted the redirect from /subdirectory from /manual, despite the root URL taking you to mainurl.com/subdirectory.

I actually managed to resolve this via the following:

    ### Sub Directory Redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondurl\.com
    RewriteRule ^manual/? https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondurl\.com
    RewriteRule ^/? https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory [R=301,L]

Comment: Glad you solved it. You should add that as answer and "accept" it to remove this question from the unanswered question queue and to possibly help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved via the following:

```
### Sub Directory Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondurl\.com
RewriteRule ^manual/? https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondurl\.com
RewriteRule ^/? https://www.mainurl.com/subdirectory [R=301,L]
```

Hope someone else might find some use for it! Thanks all.